# Parse - Resetting Passwords on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform

I'm trying to use the ParseUser.RequestPasswordResetAsync method, but I don't know how to configure Parse passing the emailAdapter.

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
{
    ApplicationId = parseApplicationId,
    WindowsKey = parseDotNetKey,
    Server = parseServerUrl
});

await ParseUser.RequestPasswordResetAsync(email);
```

Comment: Well considering that Parse.com shut down on January 30th, 2017, that's likely your issue. See: https://parseplatform.github.io/migration/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm hosting my own parse server. I just don't know how to configure the e-mail adapter.

Comment: I found the answer in this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-mailgun